# react, next.js, gatsby.js - does one need to learn react first before diving into next.js or gatsby.js?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, next.js

I've been looking at newest js frameworks (as always there are too many of them..) and came across gatsby and next that claim to relief few pains from developing with react.

I'm specifically looking at building static websites with js such as next.js or gatsby.js

Can someone please explain me do I need to master React.js in order to start developing in next.js or gatsby.js?

Comment: That's what I hate most about Javascript - too volatile.

Comment: Which framework have you chosen to work with?

Comment: Java and Spring Boot.  You can keep JavaScript.  I would stick to React.js over Angular.js, because it's lighter.  That wasn't the case while Facebook maintained that onerous licensing.  The whole space is too Wild Wild West for me.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to *master* React, but you should have at least some React knowledge as they are both built upon React, and the flow of the work is hugely based upon the React way of doing things.

Definitely go through the [official React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) if nothing else before learning Gatsby or Next.js, it will really help you understand what you're doing and why you're doing it, rather than blindly copying and pasting code from their examples without knowing what it means.

Comment: Thx Mark for reply. I've already did the nextjs tutorial and halfway through gatsby and started looking into react tutorial and definitely can see similarities. Having said that I can read the differences stated by the official websites (gatsby, next, react) of why they are different from each other.
But at the end of the day how the difference will impact my long term dev?

Comment: @petrasJ - react (like most things) is easy to learn but difficult to master. It's essential that you understand the basics of react (props, state, etc) if you want to use nextjs or gatsby. As far as I understand it, gatsby builds static sites based on react code while nextjs can do both static & server side rendered. If I were to build something like stackoverflow, I would use nextjs for better SEO. If I were to build a marketing site, I might use gatsby as I wouldn't need a server and hosting would be cheaper.

Comment: @petrasJ Scott essentially stated the main difference between Gatsby and Next.js. Taking long term development into account though, nobody knows how long either of them, or even React, will be around. Don't get too invested in these technologies, for this reason - above all, they're all built on JavaScript, so your best bet is to learn these tools as far as understanding when to and when not to use them to achieve what you want for what you are building, but put your main focus on understanding the intricacies of JavaScript, as it will outlive all of the tools which have been built upon it.